# Can't find/load swt-gtk

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to run an internal web browser using JWebBrowser. When I run the application in Netbeans environment it works perfectly. However, when I build the project and run the jar file I'm getting the following error:

```
NativeSwing[1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could
not load SWT library. Reasons:
NativeSwing[1]: no swt-gtk-3721 in java.library.path
NativeSwing[1]: no swt-gtk in java.library.path
NativeSwing[1]: Can't load library: C:\Users\CCS.swt\lib\win32\amd64\swt-gtk-3721.dll
NativeSwing[1]: Can't load library: C:\Users\CCS.swt\lib\win32\amd64\swt-gtk.dll
```

I'm including the following libraries to the project:

```
DJNativeSwing.jar
DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar
DJNativeSwing-SWTAPI.jar
DJNativeSwing-SWTCore.jar
MozillaInterfaces-1.8.1.3.jar
swt.jar (version 3.7M5 for 64 bits.)
jna_WindowUtils.jar
jna-3.2.4.jar
```

and they're referenced by Manifest.MF by this way

```
Class-Path: lib/DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar lib/DJNativeSwing-SWTAPI.jar lib
/DJNativeSwing-SWTCore.jar lib/MozillaInterfaces-1.8.1.3.jar lib/DJNa
tiveSwing.jar lib/swt.jar lib/jna-3.2.4.jar lib/jna_WindowUtils.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: by default Netbeans create an `dist` folder, to distribute whole folder

Comment: So? I don't know what are you trying to say with that answer sorry.

Comment: I use `java -cp ./Navegador.jar;./lib/DJNativeSwing.jar;./lib/DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar;./lib/DJNativeSwing-SWTAPI.jar;./lib/DJNativeSwing-SWTCore.jar;./lib/MozillaInterfaces-1.8.1.3.jar;./lib/swt.jar; navegador.Main`. What I don't understand is what you want to say when talking about `dist` folder. (It cointains the runnable jar file and the `lib` folder)

Comment: its contains all that you needed, then is required onla to call proper path to the Xxx.jar, try that whats happened, for example is the same like as when you double click to the Xxx.jar

Comment: The jar file is referencing properly the lib folder where netbeans moved the needed jars. However when I call it by console, double clicking or right button -> Open with -> Java(TM) Platform Binary I'm getting the same error. I read something about SWT generates the dll files according to the version but this team is not doing it (in 64 bits). When I run in Netbeans (JVM 32 bits and using swt-32bits.jar instead swt-64bits.jar) I get generated this files: `swt-awt-win32-3721.dll` and `swt-win32-3721.dll` so may be the problem is about generating the dll files in 64 bits?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The problem was about the dll generation. I was using 3.7m5 version, I downloaded a previous version (3.7) and the application ran properly.
Thank you for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `java.library.path` in the `java` command and aim it at the path to your `.dll` files. For example,

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib -cp ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Seems like the real problem is about dll generation, so if I find the solution I will post it here.